# Laravel API Request Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello: I am writing an api with Laravel.

When I try to use request validation in the controller, I get a 405 method not allowed. When I remove the request validation, everything runs smoothly.

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('product/create', 'Api\v1\ProductController@create');
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateProduct;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Handlers\Products;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * Create Product.
     */
    public function create(CreateProduct $request)
    {
       echo 'product created...';
    }
}
```

Here is my request validator:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateProduct extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function rules()
     {
         return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'short_description' => 'required'
         ];
    }

     /**
     * Set custom validation messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'Please enter a title.',
            'price.required' => 'Please enter a price.',
            'short_description.required' => 'Please enter a short description.'
        ];
    }
}
```

When I remove "CreateProduct $request" from the "create" method, everything works.

How can I use Laravel's request validation for api calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set validation in Product Controller.

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
   $rules=array(
            'title' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'short_description' => 'required'
        );
   $messages=array(
        'title.required' => 'Please enter a title.',
        'price.required' => 'Please enter a price.',
        'short_description.required' => 'Please enter a short description.'
    );
        $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),$rules,$messages);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            $messages=$validator->messages();
            $errors=$messages->all();
            return $this->respondWithError($errors,500);
        }
    echo 'product created...';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to remove all validation from controllers, reason being, my api and web uses the same validation and I am strictly using the DRY methodology as much as I can. So, I created my own validation classes with rules and messages methods which returns the same as a Request validator. I just inject them in the controller and use the Validator::make() and all validation rules/messages are kept out of the controllers.

Answer (score 2):

as @oseintow suggested:

```
if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
    return response()->json(['errors'=>$exception->errors()], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was testing my API with PostMan. It turns out **I was using the wrong Headers** (Accept and Content-Type should be application/json but instead I was using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded for Content-Type).

After correcting that the custom request was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your exception > handler.php > render method

```
if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException){}

return parent::render($request, $exception);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

just simply add ","

i think after this every thing run smoothly

this is how i use rules for code readability

https://pastebin.com/ivBEf7mT

```
 public function rules()
     {
         return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'short_description' => 'required',
         ];
    }
```